# Adding multiple statements to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cartodb

I'm getting my data like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'php/get_all_attri.php',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                col_name: firstSel
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var total_statement = {};
               $.each(data, function(i, data) {
                console.log(data.attri_1);
            });

                }
            });
```

In the console, this returns the possible values for my query such as 18 19 20 21, etc.

They can also be strings like TRUE FALSE.

What I need is for these values to create statements that are used to build a map using cartoDB/leaflet. Here's the function:

```
function goMap3() {

        var layerSource = {
            user_name: 'me',
            type: 'cartodb',
            sublayers: [{
                sql: "SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator FROM mytable where attribute='" + attr_value + "'",
                cartocss: "#location_fusion_table {marker-fill:#1d5492;marker-width:5;marker-line-width: 0.3;marker-line-color:#fff;marker-allow-overlap: true;"}
            }, ]
        };
        cartodb.createLayer(map_object, layerSource, options)
            .addTo(map_object);
    }
```

What I need to happen is for this entire part to be written as many times as there are different values returned by my AJAX.

```
          {
                sql: "SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator FROM mytable where attribute='" + attr_value + "'",
                cartocss: "#location_fusion_table {marker-fill:#1d5492;marker-width:5;marker-line-width: 0.3;marker-line-color:#fff;marker-allow-overlap: true;"}
            },
```

In this case, `attr_value` is what needs to be replaced each time with the values from AJAX. This would allow my entire function to look something like this:

```
function goMap3() {

        var layerSource = {
            user_name: 'me',
            type: 'cartodb',
            sublayers: [{
                sql: "SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator FROM mytable where attribute='17'",
                cartocss: "#location_fusion_table {marker-fill:#1d5492;marker-width:5;marker-line-width: 0.3;marker-line-color:#fff;marker-allow-overlap: true;"}
            }, 
  {
                sql: "SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator FROM mytable where attribute='18'",
                cartocss: "#location_fusion_table {marker-fill:#1d5492;marker-width:5;marker-line-width: 0.3;marker-line-color:#fff;marker-allow-overlap: true;"}
            },
  {
                sql: "SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator FROM mytable where attribute='19'",
                cartocss: "#location_fusion_table {marker-fill:#1d5492;marker-width:5;marker-line-width: 0.3;marker-line-color:#fff;marker-allow-overlap: true;"}
            },]
        };
        cartodb.createLayer(map_object, layerSource, options)
            .addTo(map_object);
    }
```

In summary: I'm trying to figure out how I end up with that last function that I have in my question. I need to make a number of those "sublayers" to match the number of values returned from my AJAX and those values filled in the correct area in the sublayer statements.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are asking..

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how I end up with that last function that I have in my question. I need to make a number of those "sublayers" to match the number of values returned from my AJAX and those values filled in the correct area in the sublayer statements.

Comment: How about that? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/29291459/1330180)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't multiple statements, they're just elements of an array. You can simply add to the array in the `$.each()` loop:

```
function goMap3(data) {

    var sublayers = [];
    $.each(data, function(i, attr_value) {
        sublayers.push({
            sql: "SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator FROM mytable where attribute='" + attr_value + "'",
            cartocss: "#location_fusion_table {marker-fill:#1d5492;marker-width:5;marker-line-width: 0.3;marker-line-color:#fff;marker-allow-overlap: true;"
        });
    });

    var layerSource = {
        user_name: 'me',
        type: 'cartodb',
        sublayers: sublayers
    };
    cartodb.createLayer(map_object, layerSource, options)
        .addTo(map_object);
}
```

Then you can call `geoMap3(data)` from the AJAX success function.

Comment: Took me a little bit of tinkering, but I've got it. Thank you! Appreciate the extra explanation. I did just realize one thing, I need a different color for `marker-fill` for each element. Any thoughts on how to begin to do that?

Comment: Calculate the color into a variable, and use string concatenation to put it into the `cartocss` property.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to loop for each entry in the array.Just send your data to this function and it will create the object

```
   function goMap3(data) {

    var layerSource = {
        user_name: 'me',
        type: 'cartodb',
        sublayers: []
    };

    //Adds a new sublayer to the layerSource object every iteration. 
    $.each(data, function (i, attr_value) {
        layerSource.sublayers.push({
            sql: "SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator FROM mytable where attribute='" + attr_value + "'",
            cartocss: "#location_fusion_table {marker-fill:#1d5492;marker-width:5;marker-line-width: 0.3;marker- line-color:#fff;marker-allow-overlap: true;"
        });
    });

    cartodb.createLayer(map_object, layerSource, options)
        .addTo(map_object);
}
```

Comment: Right...I got it if I know exactly how many values are returned from my AJAX, but I don't. Sometimes it could be 5 and sometimes 2 or 10. So, I need to build as many of these sublayer statements as I have values returned.

Comment: Oh, ill fix now then for your solution

Comment: Amended answer should work for your solution. You could place the whole inner function inside your "success: function(data){}"